# Lightning Data Table Is Not responsive style not apply to different screen size

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

Data Table style is not changing according to all screen sizes, It becomes empty if it has single column

[image].

Comment: This is known issue see [this](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018C5BQAU)